# Yii 2 create url with parameters doesn't work

Tags: php, url, yii2, file-get-contents

I have an action which takes two parameters:

```
class TestController extends \yii\web\Controller
{
    public function actionDisplay($name, $value)
    {
       var_dump($name, $value);
    }
}
```

I use `Url::to()` to create the url:

```
yii\helpers\Url::to(['/test/display', 'name' => 'myname', 'value' =>'myvalue'], true);
// http://mysite/display?name=myname&value=myvalue
```

I then use `file_get_contents()` to obtain the data the url should return but on my linux server the url is not good:

```
http://mysite/display?name=myname&amp;value=myvalue
```

I am getting the &amp and the second parameter does not get the value, which throws

> Missing required parameters: value

It works fine on my local Xamp server

Comment: @DanilaGanchar: Regarding the yii tag: It says in the description that "This tag is a general tag used for both Yii and Yii2.". Could you please undo any edits where you removed the [tag:yii] tag?

Answer (score 1):

Try this, i hope this will help you

```
 class TestController extends \yii\web\Controller {
     public function actionDisplay($name, $value)
     {
        $var = var_dump($name, $value);
        return $var;
     } 
 }
```